# How to create multiple roles for single user in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am trying to create a web application using ruby on rails. In this application a user has multiple roles like

1. role1 = teacher
2. role2 = student
3. role3 = staff

But the thing is a user can switch between these roles by changing account settings in the application.

eg : 
**Student can also change his role as teacher and then they can teach someothers**

When they change the role the pages, timeline, homepage everything should be display according to their current role.

How can i model the database for this and how can i perform the associations for this ?

I am new to ruby on rails so please help & thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ofcourse! you can keep track of current user and then you assign user role when they switch.

[image: Perfect illustration for this scenario]

If not you can also use [rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) gem to add or remove roles and `[cancan][3]` gem for authorization.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a list of user roles and also track something called a current role.

Comment: But how can i change the pages dynamically when they switch the roles ?